# Same NSPredicate fetch different NSManagedObject in different context after merging

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data

I'm working on a multi-thread app. I need to create a NSManagedObjectContext run on background thread (named it privateContext), do some updating, inserting and deleting things on same NSPersistentStoreCoordinator of mainContext. After privateContext is saved, I merge changes of privateContext with mainContext.

If I create a NSManagedObject on mainContext, it is **temporary** without any save operation and objectID.URIRepresentation is like **x-coredata:///ManagedObject/XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX**.

Then I go to background thread and fetch with same NSPredicate on privateContext. The NSManagedObject I get is now **x-coredata://XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX/ManagedObject/p1**, which means it's **not temporary**.

After I do some updating on this object, save privateContext and merge with mainContext. I fetch with same NSPredicate on mainContext, I get a **temporary object** finally and all changes are gone.

And if I turn the app off and re-open it, **all changes are back**, and I'll get a **persistent object**...

#### EDIT

My question is how to fetch the right object (not temporary one) on mainContext after merging?

#### EDIT (codes about privateContext and mainContext)

```
NSManagedObjectContext *privateContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
[privateContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[mainContext persistentStoreCoordinator]];
[privateContext setUndoManager:nil];

// Inserting, updating and deleting on privateContext

if ([privateContext hasChanges]) {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(privateContextDidSaveNotification:)
                                                 name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                               object:privateContext];
    NSError *saveError;
    if (![privateContext save:&saveError]) {
        // Error logs
    }
    
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                                  object:privateContext];
}
```

Here's privateContextDidSaveNotification: selector

```
- (void)privateContextDidSaveNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [mainContext performBlock:^{
        [mainContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Ummm...  What's your question?

Comment: @JodyHagins Sorry, I didn't say it clearly. My question is how to fetch the right object (not temporary one) on mainContext after merging?

Comment: What is your entire hierarchy?  Is the private context the parent of the main context, or is there another context involved as well?

Comment: @JodyHagins privateContext was created from [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType], and set the same persistentStoreCoordinator with mainContext

Comment: That's not what I am asking...  I am asking about the main context (and any other contexts)... basically what contexts are involved, how are they created, and how are they related.  How you deal with temporary objects in part depends on how your contexts are related.